# Dockerize Postgres Database

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to create e and connect a Postgres Database with docker

These are the commands that I am using on my commmand prompt:

```
docker pull postgres

docker run -d -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin -e POSTGRES_USER=admin -e POSTGRES_DB=userdb -v C:\postgres_container_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data --name=postgres_con postgres
```

Then in order to take IPAddress I use the command: `docker inspect`

But When I try to use these properties on my application properties of spring:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.2:5432/userdb
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
```

I recieve this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:331) ~[postgresql-42.3.8.jar:42.3.8]
```

Comment: The whole point of mapping the port is so you can use `localhost:5432` and not have to look up the IP address

Comment: Ok, but if i set in dbeaver: user=admin password=admin and database=userdb work localhost i recieve error about password…it s very strange

Comment: Maybe there's a different username/password defined in the database already. From the docs: "Warning: the Docker specific variables will only have an effect if you start the container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing database will be left untouched on container startup."